# Undefined identifier on for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting data from mysql and display it in HTML table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
  <?php foreach($fetch2 as $l2){?>

     <tr id="<?php echo $l2['cid'] ?>">
         <td><?php echo $l2['cname'] ?></td><td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $l2['cid'] ?>" id="<?php echo $l2['cid'] ?>" value="" /></td>
     </tr>
  <?php }?>
</table>
```

Now when the value of each input is changed by user, I need to update the database. So I did a jquery iterate function:

```
for (int i=0; i<=33; i++) //because all inputs have id as numbers
{
    var id = $("#"+i).attr('id') //to get the id of all inputs
    var idValue = $("#"+i).val();

    //Send these value to php to update the database.
    //Ajax...

}
```

But I am getting undefined identifier on the `for` loop.

How to fix it, or is there any other method

Comment: `int` means nothing in Javascript; this isn't Java. Use `let` instead.

Comment: Directly use:- `for (i=0; i<=33; i++){`  or `for (var i=0; i<=33; i++){` or `for (let i=0; i<=33; i++){`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Do not implicitly create global variables.

Comment: that is it. thanks.

Comment: @am909090  better to close question now, because it's really not useful for anybody.Up-to-you BTW

Comment: If you want to make it dynamic, so you can have N of rows, you could give them the same class, use jquery to select them by class and loop over that instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance but it is not reading the id when using `$("#"+i).attr('id')`

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense; when you use `#` you're indicating that you're searching for an element with an ID of `i`, so what would be the point of getting its `id` again? You already have it; it is `i`.

Comment: sorry I am getting i, but I am not getting the value of the input of i @CertainPerformance using this `var idValue = $("#"+i).val();`

Comment: at the console i can see that i is 2 but value is undefined

Comment: @am909090 are you giving your <tr> the same id as your input field?

Answer (score -1):

Since nothing happens after i comment, I'm gonna give it a shot.

First. If i read your code right. you give the same id to your table row 
and the input within the table row

id should be unique. so this should be change, and might be why you can't get your input value.

Second, Why not make it dynamic, so you don't need to hard code your loop count?

Give your table row the same css class, use Jquery to select it and find your input.
after this, you can manipulate the value of the input.

I made a fiddle, that show what i mean, and i hope this would help.
Remember to include jquery to the page where you are going to use it.

```js
// Running when doc is ready
$(function() {

//Looping over every TR with class "tablerow"
  $.each($(".tableRow"), function(index, value) {
  
  //Finding input field in row
   var inputElment = $(value).find("input");
    //getting input's id value
   var inputId = inputElment.prop("id");
    
    // setting input's value
    inputElment.val("Row input id was: " + inputId);
    
    //reading value from the input element
    console.log(inputElment.val())
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="tableRow">
    <td>
      <input id="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableRow">
    <td>
      <input id="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableRow">
    <td>
      <input id="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableRow">
    <td>
      <input id="4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```